# How do I format an array to break every five elements into new line in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

So I have an array. I want to take the first elements and break them into new line. So my array is =

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How do I print it as

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

Thanks.

Comment: when you say format like so, you mean print it like this? or have in a variable?

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't very clear. Do you mean when you print the contents of the array you want to print 5 elements, then move onto a new line?

Comment: Sorry, i meant print it like this.

Comment: @NicholasSmith yes, I want to print 5 elements, then move onto a new line. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use the [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method of the Enumerator class to split your original array into arrays that consist of five elements each and the [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) method of the Array class to convert the five element arrays to strings:

```
a.each_slice(5) { |x|
  puts x.join
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.each_index do |i|
  puts if i%5 == 0
  print a[i]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = (1..25).to_a    
(a.size / 5).times {|i| puts a.slice(i*5, 5).join}
```

> 12345
>   678910
>   1112131215
>   1617181920
>   2122232425

[`Array#slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice) takes an index and a length. In this case, every 5 elements, slice out a piece of 5 elements. [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) then takes those elements and puts them together into a string.